# JavaScript game - how can I call new instances of the object automatically

Tags: javascript

I am working on learning JavaScript composition over inheritance and I am struggling with a few concepts. One being, the game presents users with a random number of dogs, they are then prompted to enter how many there are.

If they get it correct, they score a point and are then presented with another number of dogs.

The thing I can't work out is how to generate new dogs each time. The below code is the simplified code setup:

```
var dog = function dog(state) {
  return {
    create: function create() {
      console.log('Create the dogs');
      this.dogIsCreated();
    },
    dogIsCreated: function dogIsCreated() {
      console.log('How many dogs do you see?');
    }
  }
}

var questionOne = dog({number: 3}).create();
```

Once they have chosen the right number, i need to effectively call:

```
var questionTwo = dog({number: 6}).create();
```

The number itself will just be a call to a random number generator, but how would I call questionTwo automatically? I have no idea where to even begin!

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you creating this for a command line? Seems weird to use console.log to communicate with a user. Either way, I'd recommend learning to use events, seems like it could be very useful here.

Comment: No not at all, this is for the web and the dogIsCreated function will populate the dom with info for the user, with event handlers for their answer. It's the next step I can't work out - how to automatically generate a new question using the factory.

Comment: In that case, when the user answers a question, why not generate a new question in the event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action of 'getting it correct' occurs because of an event. You need to hook into this event, determine true/false, and when correct call `dog({number: x}).create();`.

If your requirement is more complex than this, please clarify your question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you :) Does the re-call of dog need to be with a unique var in order to make it a separate event. I need to log state after each question to log score.

Comment: The event is fired from some DOM element, like click. If dog is within the scope of your event handler function, you can just call it as above.

Comment: Thanks DvS, will give it a go :)

Answer (score 0):

Approach this using array should provide better accessibility.

```
var dog = function dog(state) {
  return {
    answer: state.number,
    create: function create() {
      console.log('Create the dogs');
      this.dogIsCreated();
    },
    dogIsCreated: function dogIsCreated() {
      console.log('How many dogs do you see?');
    }
}
var currentQuestion = 0;
var question = [];
function nextQuestion() {
    if (currentQuestion > 0) {
      //to access the last question use question[currentQuestion] e.g. question[currentQuestion].answer
    }
    question.push(dog({number: 6}).create());
    currentQuestion++;
}
```